# Android DrawerLayout overlays background ListView

Tags: android, listview, drawerlayout

Got activity with ListView and Navigation Drawer which unfortunately overlays my ListView and I cannot have any interaction like 'onItemSelected' with it.

[That's how it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBxhV.png)

**But**

Whenever I change DrawerLayout to not cover whole activity but just 
a small piece, .

[onitemSelect is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPYAK.png)

**Below my layout code:**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="marcin.chruscicki.notefication.MainActivity"
        android:background="@color/universalBackground_DarkGray">

        ...

     <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/notesListView"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/versionTxtView" />


     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#262626" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I cannot find answer anywhere and I am sure this is just a simple thing to fix.

Comment: which listview is not working??

Comment: In DrawerLayout everything works fine.   
Problem is with ListView which is outside drawerLayout (id = "notesListView").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I just found a solution/workaround for my problem. Instead of putting Drawer Layout between other components like TextView or ListView I used [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer) linked by @neelay-srivastava and created new class + layout with alone DrawerLayout inside. Then changed all my activities to fragments. And it works.

> For futher users with same problem just remember to do not nest DrawerLayout in another activity layout between other components.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your list view is not working is because u placed it in the bottom layer and over it you placed a drawer so the drawer is over the listview and the drawer is set to match_parent

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="marcin.chruscicki.notefication.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/universalBackground_DarkGray">

    ...

 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <!-- The main content view -->
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nav"/> 

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    ...


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/notesListView"
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/versionTxtView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

try to place the list view like this **when you make a item in the layout it goes one over another that means the last you place the item will be at the front** 
you need to make the navigation drawer listviw in the fragment layout .Here is a full example how you can do[fragment example](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer) .hope this will help you.Try to make a fragment for navigation drawer its easy .

Comment: It works almost fine except now whole DrawerLayout is behind ListView. Screenshot: https://s12.postimg.org/kb4b2nzrh/stck.png

Comment: I think I did everything correctly from this tutorial but final effect is just the same as it was before. :(  
Got interaction with drawer layout but not with ListView items.   https://s17.postimg.org/twrwp01db/stc.png

Comment: Ya ,but you can do the navigation drawer through this way also